# How would you recursively instantiate nested properties by its name and apply values?

Tags: c#

I am using reflection to instantiate a class and insert values in its nested properties.

Here's an example of what im trying to do:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/pBgeeV

```
private static void ApplyValueToProperty(object entityInstance, Type instanceType, string propName, string propValue)
{
    // Current only supports an object inside another object.
    // Future TODO> GO RECURSIVE TO FIND AND INSTANTIATE ALL NESTED PROPERTIES OR CLASSES!
    if (propName.Contains("."))
    {
        string[] splittedName = propName.Split('.');
        // Get type of current property
        PropertyInfo currentProp = instanceType.GetProperty(splittedName[0]);
        Type nestedPropertyType = currentProp.PropertyType;
        // Get current object applied to this current prop
        var otherObject = currentProp.GetValue(entityInstance);
        if (otherObject == null)
        {
            // Create instance of nested property class and set its value to a new instance
            otherObject = Activator.CreateInstance(nestedPropertyType);
            currentProp.SetValue(entityInstance, otherObject);
        }
        
        SetSafePropertyValue(otherObject, nestedPropertyType, splittedName[1], propValue);
    }
    else
    {
        SetSafePropertyValue(entityInstance, instanceType, propName, propValue);
    }
}
```

1. First I create the main class outside of this method scope. (Test class).
2. Then all other propName will have the value of nested properties or classes, example:

I will have a name like "**OtherTest.AnotherTest.Name**",

- If 'Test' has another property of type 'OtherTest', it would create '**OtherTest**' and then create '**AnotherTest**' and then put value on correct 'Name'.

I would like to change the first if statement to be recursive and instantiate de correct class and insert values to the correct property. In the end I want to have a complete object created with my necessary properties instantiated and values applied.

Note: I want to avoid using GetProperties() because my class has lots of properties from base members, and it consumes a lot of memory.

Comment: Seems like you are trying to implement Deep Clone have you considered using something that is described there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-net, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects

Comment: But to create a clone I would have to firstly have an object. I have nothing, only strings with properties names and values. But didnt know about DeepClone and MemberWise clone seemed like a good solution but not for this case I think.

Comment: Instead of this line `SetSafePropertyValue(otherObject, nestedPropertyType, splittedName[1], propValue);` you could do this `ApplyValueToProperty(otherObject, otherObject.GetType(), string.Join(".", splittedName.Skip(1)), propValue);` does this help?

Comment: Well, didnt thought about that. I really need to improve on recursion! I think it will help a lot. Need to look for more edges cases in order to stop recursion. But in fact it does the job very quickly! Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, you are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this line

```
SetSafePropertyValue(otherObject, nestedPropertyType, splittedName[1], propValue);
```

you could do this

```
ApplyValueToProperty(otherObject, otherObject.GetType(), string.Join(".", splittedName.Skip(1)), propValue);
```

The idea is to recursivly call `ApplyValueToProperty` with the first part of the `propName` dropped hence the `Skip(1)` in `string.Join(".", splittedName.Skip(1))`, this will drop the first part again and again till we hit the following condition with false

```
if (propName.Contains("."))
```

The `else` part of this `if` will stop the `recursion`.